# AWS CDK - Getting InvalidRouteTableId.Malformed when creating Route Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am getting the below exception when trying to create a Route Table through AWS CDK library. I went through the naming standards and am making sure to follow it. From the exception message, it seems to be removing the "-" from the id I provided. Please let me know what could be the issue

CDK statement for creating the Route Table. I am passing the vpc id as required:

aws_cdk.aws_ec2.CfnRouteTable(self,id="rtb-0ad2be93946c6be65",vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id)

Exception:

Invalid id: "rtb0ad2be93946c6be65" (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRouteTableId.Malformed; Request ID: 342b6743-b0e3-4ceb-b86d-3ae9564f7923; Pr
oxy: null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out nothing to do with the way I was creating the route table. But rather what I was doing to create the Route later for that route table. I had to pass the route table using ".ref" rather than ".logical_id"

I am using the below code for creating the table and route now and its working fine:

route_table = aws_cdk.aws_ec2.CfnRouteTable(self,id="rtb-0ad2be93946c6be65",vpc_id=vpc.vpc_id)

target_route = aws_ec2.CfnRoute(self,id="someroutename",route_table_id=route_table.ref,gateway_id=vpn_gateway.ref,destination_cidr_block="10.0.0.0/22")

But, I do think CDK can do better with error handling